# Variable "context menu" not showing

Tags: excel, vba

More a tool question than a programming question.
Not sure if it's the proper name, but by context menu i mean the list of variable properties and methods that show up after typing a variable name and a dot. For instance, i type:

```
Dim lo As ListObject
Set lo = Sheet1.ListObjects("table1")
Dim lc As ListColumn
Set lc = lo.ListColumns(1)
Dim r As Range
Set r = lc.
```

Now after typing the last dot there, usually a menu appears where I for instance can select "DataBodyRange", useful for exploring the properties/methods of a variable of a given type when you dont exactly remember the names.

Sometimes however, these menus stop popping up. I have noticed...

1. Sometimes it is caused by there being an error in the code, though sometimes not
2. It can not work in the code for one module/sheet, but work for another

Any tips on why this is and how to solve, given that it is NOT an error in the code (my current problem is in a code that compiles and runs fine)

EDIT: Fixed the error in the code. It was written in here by hand, and my actual worksheet did not have an error (but the code was too long to portray my problem efficiently).
Note! What I did to fix it for me was to go from declaring like this:

```
Dim lc1, lc2 As ListColumn
```

To declaring like this:

```
Dim lc1 As ListColumn
Dim lc2 As ListColumn
```

I guess I should have let known in original post, though I didnt think declaring like this mattered. Should it/doest it?

Comment: But there is an error.  `Dim r A Range` is an error.  I cant offer specifics on the exact reasons Intellisense stops working but in my experience, it is either an error or late binding.  If you're not using late binding and intellisense stops working then it's time to review your code.

Comment: To find out whether there's error, I compile: Debug -> Compile

Comment: InselliSense only works when the project compiles, and only for early-bound code, so avoid any member calls against `Object` or `Variant` - exactly like you're doing with these variables (kudos!). That said the line `Dim r A Range` should be red-highlighted, or the VBE complaining with a "syntax error" on that line if you try to compile it. Voting to close as a typo, `Dim r As Range` will fix this.

Comment: Yeah it was just example code written into here by hand, so yes its As in my actual code. The big point though was to avoid "muliple dims" like... "Dim lc, lc2 as ListColumn", which at least fixed it for my current problem at hand

Comment: @gudal declaring `Dim lc1, lc2 As ListColumn` is equivalent to `Dim lc1 As Variant, lc2 As ListColumn`.  The alternative you posted is the only correct way to do it.